# meteor minimongo getting inconsistent collection.findOne() results

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, javascript-objects, minimongo

I've been trying to debug a chunk of code for some hours now, banging my head against the wall, and finally pinpointed my issues to a place in the code where assigning the results of a collection.findOne() call to a variable is giving me different data than what I see with a console.log() of the same findOne() on the previous line.

```
prePostState = function(thisStID) {  
  console.log(Students.findOne({_id:thisStID}));  
  var stTemp = Students.findOne({_id:thisStID});  
  console.log(stTmp);  
  var testsTemp = stTmp.tests;
```

The collection object has a 'tests' array. In this instance, the array contains 3 objects as its elements.

While both the console.log() lines return something like this

```
 Object {_id: "eXf9dqQbaemKS24Ti", name: "Student,Name", group: "none", site: "SiteName", tests: Array[3]}
```

Expanding each shows different data. The first one shows the correct tests: Array[3], the second one shows tests: Array[1], and the single element in that array also has data that is different from the matching element in the full array.

----Update----
Doing some further testing, I've changed the code a bit.

```
prePostState = function(thisStID) {
  console.log(Students.find({_id:thisStID}).fetch()); //1
  var stTmp = Students.find({_id:thisStID}).fetch();
  console.log(stTmp);                                 //2
  console.log(stTmp[0].tests.length);                 //3
  for(var i = 0; i < stTmp[0].tests.length; i++) {
     console.log(stTmp[0].tests[i]);                  //4
  }
```

1 Returns:

```
[Object]
  0: Object
    _id: "AqLHB8hT8GxzQ7zyD"
    group: "none"
    name: "Student,Name"
    site: "SiteName"
    tests: Array[3]
```

2 Returns:

```
[Object]
  0: Object
  _id: "AqLHB8hT8GxzQ7zyD"
  group: "none"
  name: "Student,Name"
  site: "SiteName"
  tests: Array[1]
```

3 Returns:

```
3
```

The for loop at 4 repeats three times and prints out each of the three objects in the tests array.

Obviously this means I can access the data I need. Instead of

```
var testArray = stTmp.tests;
```

Which leaves me with an array with only a single element, I will just have to get the length of stTmp.tests, and then use a for loop to access each element by index and insert them into the testArray variable.

So I can continue on, but I still don't understand the behavior I'm seeing. I'm on a bit of a timeline to keep making progress at this point, but when I have some time I may revisit this and try and replicate it in a meteorpad or other form that I can share the full code with.

Comment: I also tried var stTemp = Students.find({_id.thisStID}).fetch(); and thought for a minute it returned the correct data, but after a couple of Student.update() calls, it was returning the same incomplete/out of date data.

Comment: Post a MeteorPad or share the repo, your question is too vague and I see typos on your console logs.

Comment: Are you sure they're actually different, and it's not just the browser console behaving strangely? In chrome if you go `x = {a: {}}`, `console.log(x)`, `x.a.b = 5` and only then expand the `console.log` output then you'll see `b` being 5, even though it wasn't set at the time of the `console.log`. Trying changing your code to `console.log(JSON.stringify(...))` instead of just `console.log(...)`.

Comment: No, I'm not sure. I changed a Collection.update() elsewhere and now my issue has disappeared. I tried reverting it back to test the JSON.stringify() vs just console.log(), but even with just console.log() I'm no longer getting the incomplete array, even with the update() reverted to how I had it before. Thanks for the JSON.stringify() tip though, I wasn't aware of that. Sorry that this apparently unreproduceable glitch wasted not just a bunch of my time but the time of folks here too.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you modify a return value from Minimongo, don't expect it to persist. Minimongo was specifically written this way, so you are forced to use `update` operators to update the values.

2) The correct projection API is `Coll.find({..selector..}, {fields:{..projection..}})`

Comment: This doesn't really address the issue. I am using collection.update to make changes, and console.log(Coll.find()) or findOne() show those changes. But assigning to a variable I get different data than what I had changed using update.

Comment: @soisystems I cannot reproduce it on my machine. Perhaps a small app demonstrating an issue and an open GitHub ticket will be more appropriate here.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll put something more specific together if I get a chance. I thought I might just be missing something obvious in how minimongo works, but it must be something specific to my code.